# Port forwarding between bridged interfaces

Tags: iptables, lxc, network-bridge, port-forwarding, ebtables

So I have a bunch of bridge interfaces bound with my main ethernet device (`em1`, blame HP). These serve various LXC containers I have running on my server and easily allows me to access them from other physical devices on the network.

```
name    id                  STP   interfaces    IP
br0     8000.989096db8b8a   no    em1           10.10.0.2
                                  veth236T4V    10.10.0.15
                                  veth269GNR    10.10.0.16
                                  vethBYBC0Y    10.10.0.17
```

These all get their IPs from the main network DHCP (which assigns static leases).

I want to move a service that has been running on the main host (`em1`, `10.10.0.2`, ports 9000, 9001) to the first LXC container. I have done this and can now access things through `10.10.0.15:9000-9001`, but everything else on the network expects to see it on `10.10.0.2:9000-9001`.

Traditional port forwarding through `iptables` doesn't seem to work. I've tried:

```
-A PREROUTING -i em1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to 10.10.0.15:9000
-A PREROUTING -i em1 -p tcp --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to 10.10.0.15:9001
```

And I've tried `br0` instead of `em1` but neither work.

In a hail of 3am research I found a load of stuff suggesting I need `ebtables` but I'd never even heard of that before. Half of the problem seems to be that most people use `lxcbrN` devices with LXC but I needed the external IP. I'm not sure what I need. This isn't helped by the [`ebtables` documentation](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#all) seemingly defining the word "port" as something else.

I'm out of my depth. I can't feel the floor any more and I'm starting to tread water. Can anyone throw me a line and say for certain what *I* need to redirect a couple of ports between bridged interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use iptables. Below is a script version of a proposed solution. I do not know what iptables rules you might already have, so some merging work might be required.

```
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.02
#
# test-oli rule set 2016.01.14 Ver:0.02
#     Having tested this on my test server using port 80,
#     convert for what Oli actually wants (which I can not test).
#
# test-oli rule set 2016.01.14 Ver:0.01
#     Port forward when this computer has one nic and
#     is not a router / gateway.
#     In this case the destination is a guest VM on this
#     host but, with bridged networking and all IP addresses
#     from the main LAN, that should not be relevant.
#
#     This script may conflict with other iptables rules on the
#     host, I don't know. On my test server, clobbering the existing
#     iptables rules is O.K. because I do not use the virbr0 stuff,
#     nor the default virtual network,  anyhow.
#
#     References:
#     http://askubuntu.com/questions/720207/port-forwarding-between-bridged-interfaces
#     http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1855192
#     http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-forwarding-with-one-nic-80009/
#
#     run as sudo
#
echo "test-oli rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

# Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
# Use br0 instead of eth0. While using eth0 seems to work fine, the packet counters
# don't work, so debugging information is better and more complete using br0.
#
#
INTIF="br0"
INTIP="10.10.0.2"
FORIP="10.10.0.15"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

echo " Internal Interface: $INTIF  Internal IP: $INTIP  Forward IP $FORIP"

# CRITICAL:  Enable IP forwarding since it is disabled by default
#
echo Enabling forwarding...
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo " Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy to ACCEPT.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z
# While my references do not have it, I think this is needed.
$IPTABLES -t nat -Z

# First we change the destination of any incoming port 80 traffic
#
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $INTIF --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination $FORIP:9000
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $INTIF --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination $FORIP:9001

# And then we do the actual forward
# FORWARD rules would only be needed if the default policy is not ACCEPT
# (Shown here for completeness)
#
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -i $INTIF -d $FORIP --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -i $INTIF -d $FORIP --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT

# Now, we need to change the source address, otherwise the reply packets
# would be sent directly to the client, causing confusion.
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTIF -j SNAT --to-source $INTIP

echo "test-oli rule set version $FWVER done."
```

Comment: Well I thought this looked suspiciously like what I was already trying through ufw but I stripped it back to the (PREROUTING/FORWARD/POSTROUTING) rules, ran them and it only bloody works. Many thanks. Adding a bounty as a reward for such a thorough answer (which I will award in 24 hours when I can).

Comment: @Oli: Thank you for the extra reputation. Regardless, I was happy to help.

Comment: @DougSmythies does your solution have iptables Filtering for Bridge devices enabled or disabled? (net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables, net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables, net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables)

Comment: @naisanza : As far as I know/recall, disabled. I don't even have those files (`/proc/sys/net/bridge` does not exist).

Comment: @DougSmythies you're right, it appears that `/proc/sys/net/bridge` seems to appear in the Desktop version of Ubuntu, and not the Server version (I noticed this when I realized the Desktop version had been installed)